# How to match multiple columns in pandas DataFrame for an "interval"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, intervals

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame('filename.csv')
print(df)

order    start    end    value    
1        1342    1357    category1
1        1459    1489    category7
1        1572    1601    category23
1        1587    1599    category2
1        1591    1639    category1
....
15        792     813    category13
15        892     913    category5
....
```

So, there is an `order` column encompasses many rows each, and then a range/interval from `start` to `end` for each row. Each row then is labeled by a certain `value` (e.g. category1, category2, etc.)

Now I have another dataframe called `key_df`. It is basically the exact same format:

```
import pandas as pd
key_df = pd.DataFrame(...)
print(key_df)

order    start    end    value    
1        1284    1299    category4
1        1297    1309    category9
1        1312    1369    category3
1        1345    1392    category29
1        1371    1383    category31
....
1        1471    1501    category31
...
```

My goal is to take the `key_df` dataframe and check whether the intervals `start:end` match any of the rows in the original dataframe `df`. If it does, this row in `df` should be labeled with the `key_df` dataframe's `value` value.

In our example above, the dataframe `df` would end up like this:

```
order    start    end    value        key_value
1        1342    1357    category1    category29
1        1459    1489    category7    category31
....
```

This is because if you look at `key_df`, the row

```
1        1345    1392    category29
```

with interval `1::1345-1392` falls in the interval `1::1342-1357` in the original `df`. Likewise, the `key_df` row:

```
1        1471    1501    category31
```

corresponds to the second row in `df`:

```
1        1459    1489    category7    category31
```

I'm not entirely sure

(1) how to accomplish this task in pandas

(2) how to scale this efficiently in pandas

One could begin with an if statement, e.g.

```
if df.order == key_df.order:
    # now check intervals...somehow
```

but this doesn't take advantage of the dataframe structure. One then must check by interval, i.e. something like `(df.start =< key_df.start) && (df.end => key_df.end)`

I'm stuck. What is the most efficient way to match multiple columns in an "interval" in pandas? (Creating a new column if this condition is met is then straightforward)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), but if `DataFrames` are large, scaling is problematic:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df, key_df, on='order', how='outer', suffixes=('','_key'))
df1 = df1[(df1.start <= df1.start_key) & (df1.end <= df1.end_key)]
print (df1)
    order  start   end      value  start_key  end_key   value_key
3       1   1342  1357  category1     1345.0   1392.0  category29
4       1   1342  1357  category1     1371.0   1383.0  category31
5       1   1342  1357  category1     1471.0   1501.0  category31
11      1   1459  1489  category7     1471.0   1501.0  category31
```

EDIT by comment:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df, key_df, on='order', how='outer', suffixes=('','_key'))
df1 = df1[(df1.start <= df1.start_key) & (df1.end <= df1.end_key)]
df1 = pd.merge(df, df1, on=['order','start','end', 'value'], how='left')
print (df1)
   order  start   end       value  start_key  end_key   value_key
0      1   1342  1357   category1     1345.0   1392.0  category29
1      1   1342  1357   category1     1371.0   1383.0  category31
2      1   1342  1357   category1     1471.0   1501.0  category31
3      1   1459  1489   category7     1471.0   1501.0  category31
4      1   1572  1601  category23        NaN      NaN         NaN
5      1   1587  1599   category2        NaN      NaN         NaN
6      1   1591  1639   category1        NaN      NaN         NaN
7     15    792   813  category13        NaN      NaN         NaN
8     15    892   913   category5        NaN      NaN         NaN
```

Comment: I noticed an error here. If there is no `value_key` for a given row, this will be thrown away. For our purposes, all rows in `df` are good---none should be discarded. If no `value_key` is applicable in a given row (i.e. it doesn't fall in the interval), then a `NaN` should be recorded.

Comment: So do you need add `merge` with left join to my code? `df1 = pd.merge(df, df1, on=['order','start','end', 'value'], how='left')` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should mention this isn't scalable for dataframes around 100 MB in size (and over). I get a `MemoryError`. Any ideas how to make this more scalable? Instead of merging, many a for loop? Here's the error: 
   `File "pandas/src/join.pyx", line 187, in pandas.algos.full_outer_join`     `(pandas/algos.c:61680)`
      `File "pandas/src/join.pyx", line 196, in`
`pandas.algos._get_result_indexer (pandas/algos.c:61978)`
  ` MemoryError`

Comment: I send you email.

Comment: Email! How does that help me?